# how to know when my resource was added to my project

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, properties, .net-assembly

I need to compare the last time my project was modified (date) and when my resource (Dll for example) was added to my project.
Is there a way to get these dates? or it's just a wishful thinking ?

Comment: Without source control, yes it is wishful thinking. With source control you could look back at the versions and see when it was added. Another reason to always use source control!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [File.GetLastWriteTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime(v=vs.110).aspx) to inspect .csproj file. To know the time the dll was added, you'd need to implement some simple version controll system, and compare file versions in time.

Comment: No property to get the date when dll was added ? or on the other side to get from the project a property which says last time a resource was added?

Comment: @Damkulul the .csproj is a text file. You can see for yourself that none of this information is included.

Comment: @Damkulul No to my knowledge. You can set the FileSystemWatcher in separe process and update project properties, but it may be an overkill, depending on what you're doing.